# Any way to recover Netbeans 7.2 bookmarks navigation old style?

Tags: java, php, netbeans, ide, bookmarks

Netbeans 7.2 changed the way bookmarks works.

Before <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> moved focus up and down in the same file.

But now appears a window showing bookmarks in all files. I preferred the old way. Any way to back to old style?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open the menu `Tools -> Options`, click on `KeyMap`, search for `Bookmark`

Remove the shortcuts on `Bookmark History Popup Next` and `Bookmark History Popup Previous`; Set the keyboard combination on `Next Bookmark` and `Previous Bookmark`.

Answer (score 3):

I know a way if you still have the old version installed or are willing to re-install the old version. You can export the old keymap settings. In the old version of Netbeans:

1. Go to Tools->Options, then click on the "Keymap" tab.
2. Click on the "Manage Profiles..." button, highligh the "netbeans" profile.
3. Press the Export and choose a save location and save the keymap file.

In NetBeans 7.2:

1. Go to Tools->Options, then click on the "Keymap" tab.
2. Click on the "Manage Profiles..." button then import and navigate to the file saved in step 3 of the previous list and open it.
3. A pop up will appear to name the new profile, call it what you want.
4. Select the new profile then search for cntrl+shift+. in the "Search in Shortcuts:" text box. you should have 2 "Actions" mapped to the Shortcut, one called "Next Bookmark" and one called "Bookmark History Popup Next". Disable the keymap that says "Bookmark History Popup Next" by pressing the "..." button and "clear".
5. Repeat step 4 but with cntrl+shift+, and "Bookmark History Popup Previous".
6. Press the "okay" button and the shortcuts should behave as they previously did :)